# How to return 403 response in JSON format in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to develop a RESTful API with Laravel 5.2. I am stumbled on how to return failed authorization in JSON format. Currently, it is throwing the 403 page error instead of JSON.

Controller: `TenantController.php`

```
class TenantController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $tenant = Tenant::find($id);
        if($tenant == null) return response()->json(['error' => "Invalid tenant ID."],400);
        $this->authorize('show',$tenant);
        return $tenant;
    }
}
```

Policy: `TenantPolicy.php`

```
class TenantPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    public function show(User $user, Tenant $tenant)
    {
        $users = $tenant->users();
        return $tenant->users->contains($user->id);
    }
}
```

The authorization is currently working fine but it is showing up a 403 forbidden page instead of returning json error. Is it possible to return it as JSON for the 403? And, is it possible to make it global for all failed authorizations (not just in this controller)?

Comment: I would use a 3rd party library like dingo/api. It handled this for you, as well as versioning and transformers. https://github.com/dingo/api

Answer (score 46, accepted):

We managed to resolve this by modifying the exceptions handler found in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` adding it in the `render` function.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof AuthorizationException)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Not authorized.'],403);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work in Laravel 5.4  `dd($e instaceof AuthorizationException)`  return false.

Comment: It still works. Is your exception really an instance of AuthorizationException? Maybe you forgot to import the AuthorizationException class using the "use" operator?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, make a simple before method in your policy which will be executed prior to all other authorization checks,

```
public function before($user, $ability,Request $request)
{
    if (!yourconditiontrue) {
         if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return abort('403');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Akram, in `TenantPolicy.php`, it will have a few functions in there such as `update` and `store` and it will have different conditional statements. What should I put in the `yourconditiontrue` then?

Comment: whatever your authorization logic to return true false, if its so, then you have to do the conditions on each respective functions , let me refresh my knowledge about Laravel Policy and come back with a solution evening,

Answer (score 6):

As for the latest version of Laravel, as of now version >=7.x,

Generally setting request headers **'Accept' => 'application/json'** will tell Laravel that you expect a json response back.

For errors you need to also turn off debugging by setting the **APP_DEBUG=false** on your .env file, which will make sure the response is json and no stacktrace is provided.

Answer (score 5):

You can intercept the exception

```
    try {
        $this->authorize('update', $data);
    } catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return response()->json(null, 403);
    }
```

Comment: More precisely, catch `\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but if you don't want to return json for every route you can handle this with middleware.

A brief outline of how to do this:

Create an `ApiAuthorization` class and extend your main auth class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

class ApiAuthorization extends Authorize
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability, ...$models)
    {
        try {
            $this->auth->authenticate();

            $this->gate->authorize($ability, $this->getGateArguments($request, $models));
        } catch (AuthorizationException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not authorized.'],403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add the middleware to `$routeMiddleware` in `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
'api.can' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthorization::class,
```

Update your route.  You can now use your new api auth middleware by calling `api.can` similar to [the example in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-middleware)

```
    Route::get('tenant', [
        'as' => 'api.tenant',
        'uses' => 'TenantController@show'
    ])->middleware('api.can:show,tenant');
```

This method allows you to return json for specific routes without modifying the global exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

I have also face the same issue in Laravel version 7.3 where the AuthorizationException is not caught. What I come to know that we have to include AuthorizationException in the Handler.php like

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

use Throwable;
use Exception;
use Request;
use Response;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException)
        {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Forbidden'], 403);
        }
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException && $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'resource not found')], 404);
        }
        
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    // ...
}
```

FYI if you just add the AuthorizationException by using the following statement

> use AuthorizationException;

It still not working. So we have to specify the fully qualified namespace path.