# Laravel authorization via middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a policy in laravel 5.3 with this two actions:

```
class ProjectPolicy {
   ...
   public function index(User $user)
   {
      return true;
   }
   public function create(User $user)
   {
      return true;
   }
   ...
}
```

and then I tried to make authorization via route group middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:index,create,App\Project']], function () {
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
});
```

ofcourse I have created Project model and controller correctly, but calling index and create actions always returns 403 forbidden response. where is the problem?

**Update:**

removing one of actions from route middleware, results correct response. something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['can:index,App\Project']], function () {
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a second Route::group block with the remaining action. That would be ...can:create,App\Project...?

Comment: yes, works but second group will depends on first one middleware result, and if first middleware return false breaks...

Comment: Maybe this will help. I'm sorry to say I don't know the answer. Just Googled the issue a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580890/how-to-return-403-response-in-json-format-in-laravel-5-2 Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the docs the `can` middleware doesn't really lend itself to resources. You could use multiple middleware calls on the group but this would mean that your use would require all privileges to access the routes.

Your alternatives are:

Add `$this->authorize(new App\Project)` to your `index` and `create` methods in your controller. Laravel will use reflection to figure out what policy to use based on the method it is called from.

Or

In the `__construct()` method of your controller you could use:

```
$this->authorizeResource(App\Project::class);
```

This will require you to 
create `update`, `view` and `delete` methods inside your Policy class. Each of these methods will be passed `User $user, Project $project` e.g.

```
public function view(User $user, Project $project)
{
   return true;
}
```

FYI, if you leave off the method name with `authorize()` or you use `authorizeResource()` Laravel will map certain method names to different policy methods i.e. :

```
[
  //ControllerMethod => PolicyMethod
    'show'    => 'view',
    'create'  => 'create',
    'store'   => 'create',
    'edit'    => 'update',
    'update'  => 'update',
    'destroy' => 'delete',
];
```

You can override this by adding a `resourceAbilityMap()` method to your controller and returning a different array to the one above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm not sure why the AuthorizesRequests::authorizeResource method isn't documented.  It certainly should be!

Comment: @hackel There are a fair few things that are missing from the docs. You could always create an issue in the github repo or even write them up yourself and then create a pull request :)

Answer (score 5):

Spend hours on that ... 
If your controller method does not take a Model as parameter, you also have to override the `resourceMethodsWithoutModels()`.

```
protected function resourceAbilityMap()
{
    Log::info("Inside resourceAbilityMap()");
    return array_merge(parent::resourceAbilityMap(), [
        //ControllerMethod => PolicyMethod
        'index' => 'index',
        'search' => 'search'
    ]);
}


protected function resourceMethodsWithoutModels(){
    return array_merge(parent::resourceMethodsWithoutModels(), [
        'search'
    ]);
}
```